# rounding error in simple assignment

Tags: errors, calculations, points

I have a simple assignment in LuaTex:

`\dimen1 = 210mm`

Now I print the value

`\the\dimen1`

The result is:
`597.50787pt`

Calculating back with `1pt = 0.351mm` is: `209.725...mm`.
This is an error of more than a quarter mm. Seems not much, but saying `\pagewidth = 210mm`
means, my page is a quarter mm too small.

When I do `\dimen2 = 598.2905983pt` (the correct value for 210mm), `\the\dimen2` shows the nearly correct `598.2906pt`.

Why is the error so unexpected large when assigning millimeters? Am I using the wrong factor between pt and mm? Or is 0.351 rounded itself?

Thanks for all answers
Peter

Answer (score 2):

Oh, I found the answer myself.
0,351 is a rounded value. Donald Knuth set his TeX-pt to exact 1⁄72.27inch which is near to 0.35145980mm.
It's so easy :-)

Found the answer here: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Point_(typography)

Thanks for reading
Peter